How can flyby missions work?
I understand that a small object (Spacecraft) which approaches a large body (planet) will be accelerated.
But as the gravitational field is a gradient field, the small object should lose all the velocity gained during approach when it departs again from the planet.
So my question is how a spacecraft can draw a positive resulting amount of energy from a planet when doing a flyby operation so that it can leave the planet system with a velocity higher than the velocity when entering the planet system.

In some maneuvers, the spacecraft burns propellant at a specific point to make use of the Oberth effect

"willl be accelerated". Aye. But that can result in both "gain speed at the end of the maneuvre" and "loose speed" way.  As for the rest, it always confused me until I realised that the lanet used in the grav.assist is not stationary, and that we steal/give energy to it.

It is NOT a satellite unless it is orbiting the body.

Some related questions on our sister site: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/134473/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53050/123208

why not go to the specialists: on https://science.nasa.gov/mission/cassini/gravity-assists/  are several articles explaining gravity assits and other space travel techniques

Essentially, by (slightly) slowing down the object that you are using for the gravitational assist. What happens is that, during the flyby, a small amount of energy from the objects momentum is transferred (slowing the object down slightly) to the satellite, which receives that momentum and is sped up.
The momentum gained from just descending normally and then lost when leaving the planet's sphere of influence will cancel each other out, that is not being counted here.

It's important to note that a gravity assist is only possible off a body moving with respect to some external reference frame. It doesn't work in the frame of the planet.
As the object falls toward the planet, it converts the gravitational potential energy of the system into kinetic energy. As it leaves, it converts that kinetic energy back into potential energy. It seems like there should be no gain in energy for the falling object. In the frame of the planet, there isn't (although keep in mind the planet itself is a non-inertial accelerating frame, which accounts for the seeming discrepancy).
The key is to note that for an approach-from-behind slingshot maneuver, the planet has its own velocity in the external reference frame. As the planet "runs away" from the approaching body, the planet's own kinetic energy gets turned into potential energy of position between the planet and the object, which gets transferred to the object in the form of kinetic energy as it falls (it is the imbalance in masses that causes energy to transfer from the planet to the object rather than vice versa).
To think about it another way, in the planet-centered frame, the object's  velocity vector has identical magnitude (but different direction) on the way in and out. In the sun-centered frame, the object's velocity vectors are whatever they were in the planet frame, plus the planet's own velocity vector. But because velocity is a vector, the directionality is important for the sum - the magnitudes of the sum vector need not be equal on the way in and out in the sun-centered frame. See the diagram below, showing the planet-relative velocity of the object in red, the Sun-relative velocity of the planet in blue, and the resulting Sun-relative velocity of the object in green. The planet-relative velocity vectors of the object are equal in magnitude at the start and end of the slingshot, but the Sun-relative velocity vectors are not.

The net velocity vector will depend greatly on the directional alignment of the initial and final planet-centered velocity vectors of the object with the planet's own sun-centered velocity vector. Contrast this with the planet-centered frame, where all directions are identical and there is no preferred direction of orbital motion, again pointing to the fact that a gravity assist doesn't work in the planet frame.

+1 for providing the illustration

+1 for the third paragraph and for summarizing it as "In the sun-centered frame, the object's velocity vectors are whatever they were in the planet frame, plus the planet's own velocity vector." Perhaps bold that to make the answer skim-able.

The description of a flyby in the OP is correct … but only for a 2-body system: in a 2-body universe, a gravitational assist is not possible.
But in a 3-body system consisting of a small satellite, a planet, and massive sun, it is possible.
I find it very difficult to intuitively understand gravitational assists, but the best explanations I have found all focus on which frame of reference you are using at a given point in the problem.
From the planet's frame of reference, the encounter is exactly as described in the OP: a 2-body hyperbolic trajectory. But when we talk about the satellite “picking up speed”, we are referring to the satellite’s orbital speed with respect to the Sun’s frame of reference, not the planet's.
If you look at the encounter as a Kerbal-esque patched conic problem, the satellite follows an elliptical Solar orbit until it enters the planet’s sphere of influence (the point where the planet's gravitational attraction is greater than the Sun's). At that point the satellite switches to a hyperbolic trajectory past the planet. It is “carried along” in the planet’s sphere of influence during this hyperbolic phase. When it exits the planet's sphere of influence, it switches to a new solar elliptical orbit, different to the initial solar orbit, with a higher (or lower) speed as measured in the Solar frame of reference.
Of course, this explanation is not “true”. It is just a conceptual convenience. There is no wall in space that defines this imaginary sphere of influence. But then, there is no 3D grid of lines that defines a frame of reference, either.
It is interesting that the Sun plays no part in the encounter other than providing a frame of reference to measure against.

Good observation. "It is interesting that the Sun plays no part in the encounter other than providing a frame of reference to measure against." -> this is not accurate: the assisting planet is orbiting the Sun and the spacecraft's gain in energy is the planet's loss in energy in its orbit around the Sun. However, numerically speaking, the loss of the planet's orbital energy is of course negligible.

But why does it leave the planet’s sphere of influence at a different speed? When I jump into a hole through a planet I don’t come out at a lower (or higher) speed at the other side.

@Ludo No, the observed KE is the same in the Sun-centered reference frame whether the Sun is there or not. It doesn't matter if anything is actually orbiting the Sun. You could get a gravity assist off a rogue planet in deep space with respect to some external reference frame, no third body needed at all. I find it incorrect to say gravity assists aren't possible with only 2 bodies - you don't need a third body to center the reference frame elsewhere.

A thought experiment that helps is realizing that gravity assist isn't just good at speeding you up. You can use it to slow down. Just have to hit the planets gravity well from the other side so you're speeding it up and you down. You just need the suns, or some,  frame of reference so that "the other side" has some meaning.

Very insightful comment. I hadn't realized that.


the small object should lose all the velocity gained during approach when it departs again from the planet.

Yes, but only in the reference frame of that planet.
Imagine you're standing next to a railroad with a tennis ball in your hands, and there's a train approaching. Throw the tennis ball in the path of the train, so that it hits the front of the train right as the train passes, but in a way that the ball doesn't have much speed from your point of view.
(Please don't actually do this!)
The ball will bounce against the front of the train, and will gain quite a lot of speed. From your point of view, the ball gained a lot of speed. From the point of view of the train on the other hand, the ball had quite some speed, and bounced of with that same speed (minus losses because the collision was not 100% elastic).
The mechanism by which the train changes speed and direction of the ball is different from the mechanism by which a planet changes speed and direction of a spacecraft, but the effect is comparable.

+1 for providing a very simple to understand analoguous situation which does not need geometric intuition, but nevertheless illustrates the "reference frame choice influences result" aspect of the other answers.

Although the question already has good answers, I'd like to give it one more try from a different point of view, concentrating on the two different reference frames (sun-centered and planet-centered) that have to be considered here.

But as the gravitational field is a gradient field, the small object
should lose all the velocity gained during approach when it departs
again from the planet.

That's abolutely correct, in the reference frame that moves with the planet. If a small object enters the planet's system with e.g. 10 km/s, it leaves with the same speed - relative to the planet. But in

it can leave the planet system with a velocity higher than the
velocity when entering the planet system

we talk about a velocity relative to a different reference frame, centered at the sun.
(In the following paragraphs, I deliberately ignore the fact that the sun and the planet don't follow linear trajectories and so cannot exactly be treated as inertial systems, but for the short peroid of the flyby, the curvation of their movements can be ignored, making it easier to explain the underlying principles.)
Let's assume a simple example:

The satellite enters the Jupiter planet system directly from the sun with 10 km/s (measured in the sun's reference frame).
Jupiter's orbital speed is about 13 km/s.
In Jupiter's frame, the satellite arrives "from ahead / from inside" with an additional 13 km/s tangential speed component, adding up to a 16 km/s entry speed relative to Jupiter.
The satelleite's hyperbolic course is planned such that it turns into the direction of movement of Jupiter, leaving parallel to Jupiter's orbital movement.
The satellite leaves the planet system with the same speed of its entry (16 km/s), expressed in Jupiter's reference frame (!). But as this reference frame moves with the planet's orbital speed of 13 km/s, its exit speed, when counted in the sun's reference frame, is now 29 km/s.


So my question is how a satellite can draw a positive resulting amount
of energy from a planet

While gravitational pull altered the velocity of the satellite, the opposite gravitational pull (Newton: actio = reactio) also altered the velocity of Jupiter (by a tiny amount, considering the expected mass ratio).
As kinetic energy can only be defined relative to some reference frame and we're interested in the speed gain relative to the sun, we'll use the sun's frame for the discussion.
While the satellite is accelerated inward/forward during the flyby, gaining kinetic energy, Jupiter gets accelerated outward/backward meaning a (tiny) decrease in speed and loss of energy.

In your example, isn’t it simply redirecting the satellite’s path but the speed is still the same? I don’t see how it’s gaining energy from Jupiter.

@Michael How do you measure speed? How do you measure kinetic energy? For both questions you need a reference frame defining "zero velocity", which could be "relative to the sun" or "relative to Jupiter", and in the "Jupiter" frame, the satellite's path is simply redirected without any change in energy. But the very same trajectory, just measured in a different reference frame "sun" means an increase in speed and energy.

+1 but a graphic (even a hand made one photographed with a mobile phone) would make the explanation a lot more clear.

Okay so sort of like jumping on and off of a passing trolley car (which is coasting at the moment), with the sidewalk as the frame of reference. You speed up a lot, meanwhile the trolley slows down a little. Or maybe a better comparison would be jumping onto a passing ice truck carrying blocks of ice. You land on top of the ice, so you mostly slip, and in fact slide off the back of the truck, but you do pick up some speed. And the truck slows slightly, but it slows even less than the trolley did.

@StevePemberton IMHO, the ice truck is not the best example, as there isn't much interaction because of the slippery ice. It's more like grabbing a bar of a passing trolley car and making a 180-degrees U-turn around that bar while keeping the momentum, so you leave the car with twice the car's speed.

@RalfKleberhoff - "there isn't much interaction".  That was the point of that example. When you land on the platform of a trolley car, or grab its hand rail, or slam into a planet you have an immediate forceful change in velocity. In the case of a flyby (or sliding on an ice truck) the exchange of energy is less forceful and takes more time. I qualified the analogy with "sort of" to make it clear that I was just making a simple analogy (a comparison highlighting a similarity between otherwise dissimilar things to help isolate and illustrate one aspect of the discussion) not a direct comparison

What If? explains this succinctly.


Gravity assists aren’t paradoxical magic. It’s just like bouncing a tennis ball off a passing truck.

The planet is orbiting around the Sun at quite a high velocity, like the truck is moving down the road. The spacecraft "bounces" off the planet and takes some energy from the planet's orbit to accelerate in the same direction, just like a ball bounces off a truck and steals some energy to accelerate in the direction the truck is moving. The planet is much larger than the spacecraft, so the planet's orbit is not noticeably affected, just like the truck's speed is not noticeably affected by the ball.
